# How to merge multiple rows in one single rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have the following temp table that has been built to list current room status in a hotel

```
    declare @CurrentDate datetime = '2016-04-21' 
    select Lodging, Room, FirstName, LastName, TempStatus, @CurrentDate as CurrentDate
    from RoomAvailability
```

This is the following result:

```
    Lodging     Room    FirstName   LastName    TempStatus  CurrentDate
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    marriok     119     Super       Man     Next guest      2016-03-24 00:00:00.000
    marriok     101     Bat         Man     Next guest      2016-03-24 00:00:00.000
    marriok     123     Aqua        Man     Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000
    marriok     103     Wonder      Woman   Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000
    marriok     101     Lex         Luthor  Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000
```

This is my expected result:

```
    Lodging     Room    CurrFirstName       CurrLastName    TempStatus      CurrentDate                 NextFistName    NextLastName    TempStatus
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    marriok     119     Super               Man             Next guest      2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     NULL            NULL            NULL
    marriok     123     Aqua                Man             Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     NULL            NULL            NULL
    marriok     103     Wonder              Woman           Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     NULL            NULL            NULL
    marriok     101     Lex                 Luthor          Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Bat             Man             Next guest
```

I tried this:

```
    declare @CurrentDate datetime = '2016-04-21' 
    select coalesce(a.Lodging, b.Lodging) as Lodging, 
        coalesce(a.Room, b.Room) as Room, 
        a.FirstName as CurrFirstName, a.LastName as CurrLastName, a.TempStatus, @CurrentDate,
        b.NextFirstName, b.NextLastName, b.TempStatus
    from RoomAvailability a
    full join RoomAvailability b
        on a.Lodging = b.Lodging
        and a.Room = b.Room
```

And I got this:

```
    Lodging     Room    CurrFirstName       CurrLastName    TempStatus      CurrentDate                 NextFistName    NextLastName    TempStatus
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    marriok     119     Super               Man             Next guest      2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Super           Man             Next guest
    marriok     101     Bat                 Man             Next guest      2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Bat             Man             Next guest
    marriok     101     Bat                 Man             Next guest      2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Lex             Luthor          Leaving today
    marriok     123     Aqua                Man             Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Aqua            Man             Leaving today
    marriok     103     Wonder              Woman           Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Wonder          Woman           Leaving today
    marriok     101     Lex                 Luthor          Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Bat             Man             Next guest
    marriok     101     Lex                 Luthor          Leaving today   2016-03-24 00:00:00.000     Lex             Luthor          Leaving today
```

So how can I get unique or merged rows and listing the people who is leaving and arriving at the same room on the same date? (Preferable without CTE)

---

**Update**

The temp table RoomAvailability was product of the 3 select statements with union all

The 3 select statements are the same, they just differ on the where clause. In this 3 select statements contain a check-in and check-out datetime columns.

My 1st select is filtered by the current date variable between the check-in and check-out date (non-inclusive). I added a column as status as 'In house'.

My 2nd select is filtered by current date variable equals to check-in and I added the status text 'Next guest'

The last select is filtered by current date variable equals to check-out and I added the status 'Leaving today'.

---

**Update 2**

This is closer that I could get without CTE

```
select coalesce(a.Lodging, b.Lodging), 
    coalesce(a.Room, b.Room), 
    a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.TempStatus, 
    b.FirstName, b.LastName, b.TempStatus,
    @CurrentDate
from RoomAvailability a
left join RoomAvailability b
    on a.Lodging = b.Lodging
    and a.Room = b.Room
    and a.TempStatus != b.TempStatus
```

But it's repeating the row for the same room at the end

```
marriok 119 Super   Man     Next guest      NULL    NULL    NULL            2016-04-21
marriok 101 Bat     Man     Next guest      Lex     Luthor  Leaving today   2016-04-21
marriok 123 Aqua    Man     Leaving today   NULL    NULL    NULL            2016-04-21
marriok 103 Wonder  Woman   Leaving today   NULL    NULL    NULL            2016-04-21
marriok 101 Lex     Luthor  Leaving today   Bat     Max     Next guest      2016-04-21 --<-- this should not be displayed
```

Comment: put your query in a subquery, add row_number, partition by room and order by tempstatus.. then in the outer query select where row_number = 1.. here's one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: do you have a unique key in your table?

Comment: @FLICKER, well just the id of the lodging and the room. This table has been built from a query with joins in order to the get the summary of the day, but we want no duplicate.

Comment: What is the order of the records? i see all records are in the same date so for Room 101, I don't know which row is older and which row is newer. if you tell me what is the order of the rows, I'll be able to make your query.

Comment: You are right, there is no specific order. It's a hotel room reservation. So for the same date you have 2 choices for a one room; someone is arriving and someone is leaving. If not, imagine that the date is yesterday, I will have those who are in "Leaving today" as in "In house" and those who are today as "Next guest" won't exist. I updated what the means of the alias of my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were on SQL 2012 and later, the finaly query would be simpler.

Assuming your data is in the table named #t

Setup data

```
create table #t (
    Lodging varchar(10)
    , Room int
    , FirstName  varchar(10)
    , LastName  varchar(10)
    , TempStatus  varchar(20)
    , CurrentDate datetime
)

insert into #t values
('marriok'     ,119     ,'Super'       ,'Man'     ,'Next guest'      ,'2016-03-24'),
('marriok'     ,101     ,'Bat'         ,'Man'     ,'Next guest'      ,'2016-03-24'),
('marriok'     ,123     ,'Aqua'        ,'Man'     ,'Leaving today'   ,'2016-03-24'),
('marriok'     ,103     ,'Wonder'      ,'Woman'   ,'Leaving today'   ,'2016-03-24'),
('marriok'     ,101     ,'Lex'         ,'Luthor'  ,'Leaving today'   ,'2016-03-24')
```

Your query will be

```
with sortIt as (
    select *, case TempStatus 
                  when 'Next guest' then 2 
                  when 'Leaving today' then 1 
              end as Sort 
    from #t
)
, addFld as (
    select t1.*, t2.FirstName as NextFirstName, t2.LastName as NextLastName
        , t2.TempStatus as NextTempStatus 
    from sortIt t1
        left join sortIt t2 on t2.Room = t1.Room and t2.Sort = t1.Sort + 1
)
, removDup as ( 
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Room order by NextFirstName desc) rn
    from addFld
)
select * from removDup
where rn = 1
```

Result

```
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+--------------+----------------+----+
| Lodging | Room | FirstName | LastName |  TempStatus   |       CurrentDate       | Sort | NextFirstName | NextLastName | NextTempStatus | rn |
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+--------------+----------------+----+
| marriok |  101 | Lex       | Luthor   | Leaving today | 2016-03-24 00:00:00.000 |    1 | Bat           | Man          | Next guest     |  1 |
| marriok |  103 | Wonder    | Woman    | Leaving today | 2016-03-24 00:00:00.000 |    1 | NULL          | NULL         | NULL           |  1 |
| marriok |  119 | Super     | Man      | Next guest    | 2016-03-24 00:00:00.000 |    2 | NULL          | NULL         | NULL           |  1 |
| marriok |  123 | Aqua      | Man      | Leaving today | 2016-03-24 00:00:00.000 |    1 | NULL          | NULL         | NULL           |  1 |
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+--------------+----------------+----+
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean with Sql2012. This also works with 2008, it's the use of CTE. I thought that it could be easier with full join, but I give up.  Because I don't understand CTEs so much, but thanks your answer saved the day. Very appreciated!!

Comment: In sql 2012 you can use LAG and LEAD functions that make the final query much shorter. Anyway, I'm glad it helped